# Detect collisions / overlap between two sprites in isometric

Tags: javascript, collision, phaser-framework

I am playing with phaser along with its isometric plugin. I am a still a newbie on the matter however.

I have 2 sprites and I want to check for intersection / overlap between them. They are 2d simple sprites. I want to check for intersection ONLY if they are side by side and that would be for some kind of melee attack.

I created an hitbox for the player (a rect) and created a function that detects if two rects intersect each other. I can actually detect collision that way but if the player is in a little bit lower position to the target (in the screen coordinate y) it also detects the collision.

I need a way to make sure the sprites are "aligned". How could I do this in isometric in order to make sprites interact with each other? I can give more informations if needed or provide code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Isometric" is just how you render the scene and shouldn't have anything to do with the collision logic. All the game objects live in the same 3D space so **colliding sprites need 3d hitboxes**.

Comment: So I should use "cube hitboxes" to detect then?